# Smart Tag missing for Syncfusion RibbonControlAdv in Visual Studio 2019 Designer after update to .NET 5

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer, .net-5, syncfusion, smart-tags

Previously, I would be able to click on this arrow to edit the properties of `RibbonControlAdv`:

[image: expected image]

However, after migrating my project to .NET 5, I can no longer see the arrow:

[image: second image]

I can, however, see it for the inner buttons:

[image: thid image]

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

*It seems this is a [known issue](https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/19702/need-to-provide-smarttags-and-designer-support-for-ribboncontroladv-control-in) and is in fact related to .NET Core. However, it doesn't seem like Syncfusion plans on fixing it as this issue must have been around since the start of .NET Core.*

As a workaround, I created a .NET Framework 4.8 project to design the ribbon form, then copied the form over to the .NET 5 project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and apparently the way .Net Core works with Windows Form is different from .Net Framework, both still don't have the same tools in windows forms (yet). See in the last line of this Microsoft roadmap that they are still looking to improve the use of Windows Forms in .Net Core to resemble that of the .Net Framework, which is great:

https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/docs/roadmap.md

Here's an article I opened on the SyncFusion forum so we can try to get around it somehow in the future:
https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/48956/ribbon-does-not-work-correctly-using-net-core

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35350493)